# Can I buy shipments of materials off settlement stores in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I've got a number of settlements in Fallout 4 with "marketplaces" where I've built a number of stores. One of them has one of each "Emporium" - that is the highest level store.

[Some NPC merchants sell shipments of materials.](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/fallout-4-list-of-vendors-who-sell-settlement-material-shipments/)

I'd assumed "Emporiums" would sell shipments of materials but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Is it possible to buy shipments of material from settlement stores, or can you only buy them from the NPC merchants?

Are there any other ways of buying shipments in settlements?

I know that Trashcan Carla sells (useful) shipments in Sanctuary Hills and Connie Abernathy sells (less useful) shipments in Abernathy Farm. I've seen references to setting up a caravan from Bunker Hill but I haven't worked out how to do that yet.

Comment: The reward of a caravan comes after a main quest is completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't prove a negative, but I've never seen any shipments from the vendors that I build.  I've stocked several with tier 4 general store vendors and they still don't have any shipments of materials.

As for Bunker Hill, it becomes a possible settlement point after a certain quest:

> The Battle for Bunker Hill

And there are shopkeepers there that sells some shipment items.  It seems to be the only possible permanent way of purchasing shipments while on a settlement.

Update:

There are a few other possible settlements with a npc vendor that sells some shipments:

Abernathy farm and covenant.  However for covenant, you need to:

> Side with Dr Chambers in order to not have to kill the town.

Comment: Outside of roving traders I meant.  The shopkeeper in bunker hill is permanent.

Comment: is the use of the spoiler tag *really* necessary?

Comment: @kalina probably not :P

Comment: There are actually many of the named NPC settlers that double as vendors and have shipments for sale. From [this very helpful Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3sx1ot/im_making_a_list_of_shipments_of_resources_that/), I see Penny & Patricia from Covenant, Kay/Lucas/Deb at Bunker Hill, Supervisor Greene at Graygarden, and Connie from Abernathy Farm, to name just a few, have various shipments for sale. Check out the link for full list of settler vendors and what shipments they have available...

Answer (score 0):

Just like the answer above I too have not been able to / or come across any settlement stores that I have set up, that offer shipments. Only junk that I have to break down myself. Even with the more expensive stalls that you can buy and set up. Diamond City is normally pretty good for shipments from the weaponry, junk store, night time robot (also from the junk store), the swatter seller, chem store and the apparel seller in the basement shop. I normally head there for my supplies. They update every 2 days ish.